# Updating user data in mongo db

Tags: node.js

I have tried updating my user data using this sample code below but i have failed it returns errors i would like  to know if there is a way i can do it

````
    Post.findById(req.params.userId).exec(function(err,user){
        res.render("home/edituser",{user:user});
    });
});


router.post("/save" ,async function(req,res){
    const user= await User.findById(req.body.userId);

    post.username=req.body.username;
    post.email=req.body.email;
    post.password=req.body.password;

    try{
        let saveUser= await user.save();
        console.log("saveuser",saveUser);
        res.redirect("/interface" + req.body.userId);
    }catch(err){
        req.flash("error","User not updated!");
        return res.redirect("/edituser");
    }
});```
````

Comment: Please share the error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you must use put request
not post
for update user data

so like this

```
    const user= await User.findById(req.body.userId);
try{
        const update={
           username:req.body.username;
           email:req.body.email;
           password:req.body.password;
        }
      User.findOneAndUpdate({userId:req.body.userId}, {$set:update}).then( 
      res.json({success:true,msg:'user data updated', update}))

   }catch(err){
            res.json(err)
    }
```

Comment: hey Amer thank you for the response its much appreciated ... i had tried to use put instead of post but the error i get is " cannot post/save"

Comment: i would really love your help on this